# PHP - Parse out characters from string

Tags: php, substring

I'm working with some strings that appear in the following formats:

```
 $string = 'Acme Building Company - BZ-INTERNAL 1';
 $string = 'Acme Building Company - TRP-SHOP-1';
 $string = 'Acme Building Company - ZJG-INTERNAL 2';
```

I now need to get to the characters in the middle of these strings and parse them out, so in the above examples I would end up with the following:

```
  BZ
  TRP
  ZJG
```

I'm looking for the most dynamic approach so I don't have to hardcode any substitution strings but haven't been able to come up with anything so far.

Comment: Will the start of the string always be the same length ? In this case `Acme Building Company - `

Comment: `preg_match('~-(.*?)-~', $string, $output);echo  $output[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explode(); PHP function like so:

```
<?php
$string = 'Acme Building Company - BZ-INTERNAL 1';
$tmp = explode('-', $string);
$middle = trim($tmp[1]);
echo $middle;
```

The output of the above code segment will be:
`BZ`

The syntax goes `explode(DELIMITER, THE_STRING);` Which returns an array.

So when we explode the given string BZ cones in the array index 1. You can use the same approach for all your strings, maybe in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Im keen to wait and see how other people would approach this question. But if you can guarantee the string will always be formatted the way you have shown I would personally try:

```
$exploded = explode('-', $string);
$intials = trim($exploded[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression will do this quite nicely.

```
$match = null;
if (preg_match('/- (.*?)-/', $string, $matches)) {
    $match = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php preg_match("/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/", $input_line, $output_array); echo trim($output_array[2]);?>
```

or

```
<?php preg_match("/(.*) - (.*)-(.*)/", $input_line, $output_array); echo $output_array[2];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second call to `strtok()` can isolate the desired substring.

Notice that the character mask on the second call includes a space so that the following value is effectively left trimmed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1jtgT))

```
$string = 'Acme Building Company - BZ-INTERNAL 1';

strtok($string, '-');
var_export(strtok('- '));
// 'BZ'
```

Answer (score -1):

@user982124 if your string format will be the same so yes you can explode() it and at the 1th index you will get your characters like:

```
<?php
 $string1 = 'Acme Building Company - BZ-INTERNAL 1';
 $string2 = 'Acme Building Company - TRP-SHOP-1';
 $string3 = 'Acme Building Company - ZJG-INTERNAL 2';

 $strArr1 = explode("-", $string1);
 echo trim($strArr1[1])."<br>";

 $strArr2 = explode("-", $string2);
 echo trim($strArr2[1])."<br>";

 $strArr3 = explode("-", $string3);
 echo trim($strArr3[1])."<br>";
```